# 64bit int Spin Box in QT

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, qt, 64-bit, controls

I'm building a windows program which shall have controls for 64bit numeric values. these controls shall be switchable to be signed or unsigned.

I found two controls:
"Spin Box"(int32) and "Double Spin Box"(double)
with double I'd be able to cover the range but it can't handle the precision.

Is there a way to change the data type of these controls?

Is it possible to create an own control which can handle signed and unsigned 64bit values?
Is it possible to create a 128bit Spin box?

The only work around I can see right now is in using a string control and manually convert to an INT64 or UINT64 but I'm not very happy with this solution

Any other Ideas?

I'm on QT 4.7.4 and VS2010 with C++
thx

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can derive `QAbstractSpinBox` and reimplement at least the virtual functions `stepBy`, `stepEnabled` and possibly `validate()` and `fixup()` for the input validation.

Comment: thx... is it possible to use this new class with the qt designer? How can I get this new widget in this "Widget Box" Toolbox?

Comment: You can either write a designer plugin, or just insert a simple `QWidget` and use the "Promote" feature (left-click on the widget in the designer) to replace it with your class, and add dynamic `LongLong` or `ULongLong` properties named "minimum", "maximum" and "value".

Comment: Ok... I took the qspinbox.cpp/.h and copied it into my project and renamed the class to CustomSpinBox. Then I added this moc thing like I did for the forms. After this I added a QWidget with the Form in QT Designer and promoted the copied customspinbox.h file. Compile of the new CustomSpinBox isn't working. warning C4273: 'CustomSpinBox::CustomSpinBox' : inconsistent dll linkage  This constructor should be exactly the same as for the original spinbox. This seems to be very complicated for me. Is there no tutorial or further reading how to extend standard control widgets?

Answer (score 6):

I don't use fixup function. See code of my Сustom QSpinBox.
class QLongLongSpinBox derived from QAbstractSpinBox

Don't forget call

```
setMaximum(std::numeric_limits<qlonglong>::max());
setMinimum(std::numeric_limits<qlonglong>::min());
```

after creating QLongLongSpinBox.

see qlonglongspinbox.h file:

```
#include <QtWidgets/QWidget>
#include <QtWidgets/QAbstractSpinBox>
#include <QtWidgets/QLineEdit>

class QLongLongSpinBoxPrivate;
class Q_WIDGETS_EXPORT QLongLongSpinBox : public QAbstractSpinBox
{
    Q_OBJECT

    Q_PROPERTY(qlonglong minimum READ minimum WRITE setMinimum)
    Q_PROPERTY(qlonglong maximum READ maximum WRITE setMaximum)

    Q_PROPERTY(qlonglong value READ value WRITE setValue NOTIFY valueChanged USER true)


    qlonglong m_minimum;
    qlonglong m_maximum;
    qlonglong m_value;

public:
    explicit QLongLongSpinBox(QWidget *parent = 0)
    {
        connect(lineEdit(), SIGNAL(textEdited(QString)), this, SLOT(onEditFinished()));
    };
    ~QLongLongSpinBox() {};

    qlonglong value() const
    {
        return m_value;
    };

    qlonglong minimum() const
    {
        return m_minimum;
    };

    void setMinimum(qlonglong min)
    {
        m_minimum = min;
    }

    qlonglong maximum() const
    {
        return m_maximum;
    };

    void setMaximum(qlonglong max)
    {
        m_maximum = max;
    }

    void setRange(qlonglong min, qlonglong max)
    {
        setMinimum(min);
        setMaximum(max);
    }

    virtual void stepBy(int steps)
    {
        auto new_value = m_value;
        if (steps < 0 && new_value + steps > new_value) {
            new_value = std::numeric_limits<qlonglong>::min();
        }
        else if (steps > 0 && new_value + steps < new_value) {
            new_value = std::numeric_limits<qlonglong>::max();
        }
        else {
            new_value += steps;
        }

        lineEdit()->setText(textFromValue(new_value));
        setValue(new_value);
    }

protected:
    //bool event(QEvent *event);
    virtual QValidator::State validate(QString &input, int &pos) const
    {
        bool ok;
        qlonglong val = input.toLongLong(&ok);
        if (!ok)
            return QValidator::Invalid;

        if (val < m_minimum || val > m_maximum)
            return QValidator::Invalid;

        return QValidator::Acceptable;
    }

    virtual qlonglong valueFromText(const QString &text) const
    {
        return text.toLongLong();
    }

    virtual QString textFromValue(qlonglong val) const
    {
        return QString::number(val);
    }
    //virtual void fixup(QString &str) const;

    virtual QAbstractSpinBox::StepEnabled stepEnabled() const
    {
        return StepUpEnabled | StepDownEnabled;
    }


public Q_SLOTS:
    void setValue(qlonglong val)
    {
        if (m_value != val) {
            lineEdit()->setText(textFromValue(val));
            m_value = val;
        }
    }

    void onEditFinished()
    {
        QString input = lineEdit()->text();
        int pos = 0;
        if (QValidator::Acceptable == validate(input, pos))
            setValue(valueFromText(input));
        else
            lineEdit()->setText(textFromValue(m_value));
    }

Q_SIGNALS:
    void valueChanged(qlonglong v);

private:
    Q_DISABLE_COPY(QLongLongSpinBox)

    Q_DECLARE_PRIVATE(QLongLongSpinBox)
};
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the example! I know this is a few years back now, but is there a reason for hte forward declared class QLongLongSpinBoxPrivate? It doesn't appear to be used anywhere

Answer (score 1):

To use you custom class (Widget) it in Qt Creator:

- create QWidget widget
- List item
- select Promote to..  in widget menu
  New Promoted Class:
  QWigdet
  Promoted class name QLongLongSpinBox
  Header file: write qlonglongspinbox.h
  Promote
- select Promote to QLongLongSpinBox
- save

You can see

```
<item>
    <widget class="QLongLongSpinBox" name="value_integer" native="true"/>
</item>
```

and:

```
<customwidgets>
  <customwidget>
   <class>QLongLongSpinBox</class>
   <extends>QWidget</extends>
   <header>qlonglongspinbox.h</header>
   <container>1</container>
  </customwidget>
</customwidgets>
```

in *.ui file

in ui_*.h generating file you see you class:

```
#include "qlonglongspinbox.h"
QLongLongSpinBox *object_name;
value_integer = new QLongLongSpinBox(YourWidgetName);
value_integer->setObjectName(QStringLiteral("value_integer"));
verticalLayout->addWidget(value_integer);
```

Answer (score 0):

Just for the sake of completeness: every time you run into a problem like this, remember that (in case everything else fails) you can just download the Qt source code and make your own `QSpinBox64` or `QSpinBox128` class in a matter of minutes by modifying the needed parts.