# QT - How can I create a scroll bar with long int (instead of int) steps?

Tags: c++, qt, max, scrollbar

I'm trying to create a QT gui application (for educational purposes), in order to access the raw data of a hard disk. I have added a table with 32+1 columns (bytes + offset) and a separate vertical scroll bar next to it. The app reads only the visible (to the table layout) bytes. An event is triggered when the user rotates the wheel over the table widget and the presented data are refreshed.

I also want the scroll bar to have similar behavior (and of course be draggable). In this case I have to set the maximum value of scroll bar (steps) to totalHdBytes/32. However, in most cases it is a long integer (not an int), therefore not acceptable from the QScrollBar object.

My question is:

How can I create a scroll bar with as many steps as I want?

Comment: can you share the source code?

Comment: I think you will not have enough display/mouse resolution to use such big values. You need to review you UX/UI. Scroll bars are not designed for accurate positioning.

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by Dmitry, it is useless (and not directly possible) to create a `QScrollBar` with that big numbers as you do not have enough display/mouse resolution. Therefore, I suggest you to do the following:

- Use a [`QLineEdit`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qlineedit.html) to input the address (optionally using [`inputMask`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qlineedit.html#inputMask-prop) or [`validator`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qlineedit.html#setValidator)) or implement your own `QScrollBox` as discussed in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8383620/64bit-int-spin-box-in-qt).
- Map the [`QScrollBar`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qscrollbar.html) range to your desired range by using a multiplication factor.

Comment: I do not want (nor wait) to see the scroll bar moving while the arrow button is pressed down. What I want is to be able to drag the bar anywhere and then 'move' the table content one row up or down when an arrow is pressed. I emphasize that the scroll bar does not 'belong' to the table widget. The content of the table always fits exactly to its size. I use a separate scroll bar as a trick, for the user to perceive that, at any time, all the content of the disk is loaded into the memory. The best solution I have implemented so far, is your second suggestion but it is not exactly what I want.

Comment: But the user would not notice the difference. So, I think it is a good solution.

Comment: The user would notice that one click on the arrow or one wheel step over the scroll bar moves the table content many (and not one) rows up or down. Anyway, it is not a major issue since I have  correctly implemented the wheel rotation over the table widget (one wheel step = one row up/down). I was just wondering how this specific operation (which I have seen in other raw data editors) could be accomplished.