# qspinbox64 in QT5.15.2

Tags: c++, qt5

I tried to create a qspinbox64 as suggested in

[64bit int Spin Box in QT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8383620/64bit-int-spin-box-in-qt)

qspinbox64.h

```
#define QSPINBOX64_H

#include <QtGui>
#include <QtWidgets>


namespace Ui {
class QSpinBox64;
}

class QSpinBox64Private;
class Q_WIDGETS_EXPORT QSpinBox64 : public QAbstractSpinBox//QSpinBox
{
    Q_OBJECT
    Q_PROPERTY(int64_t minimum READ minimum WRITE setMinimum)
    Q_PROPERTY(int64_t maximum READ maximum WRITE setMaximum)

    Q_PROPERTY(int64_t value READ value WRITE setValue NOTIFY valueChanged USER true)

    int64_t m_minimum;
    int64_t m_maximum;
    int64_t m_value;
public:
    explicit QSpinBox64(QWidget *parent = nullptr)
    {
       connect(lineEdit(), SIGNAL(textEdited(QString)), this, SLOT(onEditFinished()));
    }

    ~QSpinBox64()
    {

    }
    int64_t value() const
    {
        return m_value;
    }
    int64_t minimum() const
    {
        return m_minimum;
    }
    int64_t maximum() const
    {
        return m_maximum;
    }
    void setMinimum(int64_t min)
    {
        m_minimum = min;
    }
    void setMaximum(int64_t max)
    {
        m_maximum = max;
    }
    void setRange(int64_t min, int64_t max)
    {
        setMinimum(min);
        setMaximum(max);
    }
    virtual void stepBy(int steps)
    {
        auto new_value = m_value;
        if (steps < 0 && new_value + steps > new_value) {
            new_value = std::numeric_limits<qlonglong>::min();
        }
        else if (steps > 0 && new_value + steps < new_value) {
            new_value = std::numeric_limits<qlonglong>::max();
        }
        else {
            new_value += steps;
        }

        lineEdit()->setText(textFromValue(new_value));
        setValue(new_value);
    }

protected:
    virtual QValidator::State validate(QString &text, int &pos) const
    {
        //return validator->validate(text, pos);
        bool ok;
        int64_t val = text.toLongLong(&ok);
        if (!ok)
            return QValidator::Invalid;

        if (val < m_minimum || val > m_maximum)
            return QValidator::Invalid;

        return QValidator::Acceptable;
    }
    virtual int64_t valueFromText(const QString &text) const
    {
        bool ok;
        return text.toLongLong(&ok, 10);
    }
    virtual QString textFromValue(int64_t value) const
    {
        return QString::number(value, 10).toUpper();
    }
    virtual QAbstractSpinBox::StepEnabled stepEnabled() const;

public
    Q_SLOTS:
    void setValue(int64_t val)
    {
        if (m_value != val) {
            lineEdit()->setText(textFromValue(val));
            m_value = val;
        }
    }
    void onEditFinished()
    {
            QString input = lineEdit()->text();
            int pos = 0;
            if (QValidator::Acceptable == validate(input, pos))
                setValue(valueFromText(input));
            else
                lineEdit()->setText(textFromValue(m_value));
        }
Q_SIGNALS:
    void valueChanged(int64_t v);


private:
    Ui::QSpinBox64 *ui;

    Q_DISABLE_COPY(QSpinBox64)

    Q_DECLARE_PRIVATE(QSpinBox64)
};

#endif
```

main.cpp

```
#include <QHBoxLayout>

#include "qspinbox64.h"

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication app(argc, argv);
    QSpinBox64 spinBox;
    spinBox.setWindowTitle(QObject::tr("QSpinBox64"));
    spinBox.show();
    return app.exec();
}
```

An error occurs after compilation:

```
G:\proj\build-qspinbox64-Desktop_Qt_5_15_2_MSVC2019_64bit-Debug\debug\moc_qspinbox64.cpp:141: 
error: C2491: 'QSpinBox64::staticMetaObject': definition of dllimport static data member not allowed
```

What should I do to avoid this error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The culprit is `Q_WIDGETS_EXPORT`, defined in `qtwidgetsglobal.h`

```
#  if defined(QT_BUILD_WIDGETS_LIB)
#    define Q_WIDGETS_EXPORT Q_DECL_EXPORT
#  else
#    define Q_WIDGETS_EXPORT Q_DECL_IMPORT
#  endif
```

You should declare `QT_BUILD_WIDGETS_LIB` in your project by adding this line to the .pro file

```
DEFINES += QT_BUILD_WIDGETS_LIB
```

Some side notes:

1. You are missing the header guard `#ifndef QSPINBOX64_H`
2. The constructor should call the base class constructor and set the min/max as instructed in the original post.
3. `stepEnabled()` needs to be implemented

---

```
explicit QSpinBox64(QWidget *parent = nullptr) : QAbstractSpinBox{parent}
{
    setMaximum(std::numeric_limits<int64_t>::max());
    setMinimum(std::numeric_limits<int64_t>::min());
    connect(lineEdit(), SIGNAL(textEdited(QString)), this, SLOT(onEditFinished()));
}

virtual QAbstractSpinBox::StepEnabled stepEnabled() const
{
    return QAbstractSpinBox::StepUpEnabled | QAbstractSpinBox::StepDownEnabled;
}
```

Comment: I have considered all your recommendations. But when compiling, there were a number of errors of the linker.                                                                                       main.obj:-1: ошибка: LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: static struct QMetaObject const QApplication::staticMetaObject" (?staticMetaObject@QApplication@@2UQMetaObject@@B) referenced in function "public: static class QString __cdecl QApplication::tr(char const *,char const *,int)" (?tr@QApplication@@SA?AVQString@@PEBD0H@Z)

Comment: moc_qspinbox64.obj:-1: ошибка: LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: static struct QMetaObject const QApplication::staticMetaObject" (?staticMetaObject@QApplication@@2UQMetaObject@@B)

Comment: qspinbox64.pro                                                                                                  `QT       += core gui
greaterThan(QT_MAJOR_VERSION, 4):
{
QT += widgets
}
CONFIG += c++11
TARGET = int64spinbox
DEFINES += QT_BUILD_WIDGETS_LIB

TEMPLATE      = app
HEADERS       = \
    qspinbox64.h
SOURCES       = \
                main.cpp`

Comment: Have you run `qmake` again? I cannot replicate the problem.

Comment: Yes I have run qmake again?

Comment: This problem only occurs on windows. On Linux, everything compiles and runs. What should I do to avoid errors under windows?

Comment: You should comment, not adding answer that is not really an answer. Seems like there are more problems. You should edit the question to give more information on those new problems (error lines in compiler output, how is the lib linked). The current information is not enough.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65704129/qspinbox64-build-for-windows