# qspinbox64 build for windows

Tags: windows, qt, qt5

In [an earlier question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65578267/qspinbox64-in-qt5-15-2), I was trying to create a `QSpinBox64` class. After following the hints from the answer, the code worked on linux.
However, when building on Windows, a number of errors occur:

```
moc_qspinbox64.obj:-1: error: LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: static struct QMetaObject const QAbstractSpinBox::staticMetaObject" (?staticMetaObject@QAbstractSpinBox@@2UQMetaObject@@B)
moc_qspinbox64.obj:-1: error: LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: static struct QMetaObject const QWidget::staticMetaObject" (?staticMetaObject@QWidget@@2UQMetaObject@@B) referenced in function "public: static class QString __cdecl QWidget::tr(char const *,char const *,int)" (?tr@QWidget@@SA?AVQString@@PEBD0H@Z)
moc_qspinbox64.obj:-1: error: LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: static struct QMetaObject const QAbstractButton::staticMetaObject" (?staticMetaObject@QAbstractButton@@2UQMetaObject@@B) referenced in function "public: static class QString __cdecl QAbstractButton::tr(char const *,char const *,int)" (?tr@QAbstractButton@@SA?AVQString@@PEBD0H@Z)
```

There are a lot of errors of this type.

Environment settings related to the QT:

- QTDIR     C:\Qt\5.15.2\msvc2019_64
- QTJAVA    C:\Program Files (x86)\QuickTime\QTSystem\QTJava.zip
- QtMsBuild C:\Users\Yota\AppData\Local\QtMsBuild

QT under Windows I installed from [the official website](https://www.qt.io/download)

How to avoid these errors when building under Windows?